# Getting javascript to work after loading content via Ajax (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm having some problems with loading content via Ajax. I can't get the Woocommerce javascript to work when I am loading a product via Ajax.

The content is loaded like this:

**App.js**

```
$.post( settings.ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
        $button.prop("disabled",false);
        if(true === response.success) {
            $('.sidebar').html(response.data);
        }  else {
            $contentWrapper.find('.response').html(response.data.general).show();
        }
    } );
```

And the backend returns a template part when the request was successful.

**Ajax.php**

```
ob_start();
    if( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'my_custom_field', true ) == 1 ) {
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/book' );
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/additional-information' );
    }
    $response = ob_get_clean();
    wp_send_json_success( $response );
```

Inside the template part "book" is a single bookable product (via Woocommerce Bookings) which requires some javascript to work for selecting time/date etc. When this template part is loaded via Ajax the javascript is not working, and I can therefore not book the product.

However if I refresh the page, the bookable product will be loaded instantly without Ajax, and now everything works perfectly.

The javascript is included globally in the header of the page and is always present. But when the new content is loaded via Ajax, I guess I need to manually fire any document.ready functions that is needed for the booking form to work.

I just cant wrap my head around how I should do this, so any help is very appreciated.

Comment: It may be something related to event binding in jQuery. Can you post some of the jQuery code in the `document.ready`?

Comment: Can you attachment javascript?
I guess it does not work with dynamically change in DOM

Comment: The code in the document ready is coming from Woocommerce Bookings and is loaded on every page. I really can't seem to find it. It is used for displaying the booking calendar, but I can't (or shouldn't) make any changes in this file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use your jquery events dynamically because you DOM was changed.

Try to use:

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );
```

instead of:

```
$(selector).on( eventName, function(){} );
```

and etc...

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. The script that triggers the Ajax call is working. But an external script which is coming from Woocommerce Bookings is not working. This script is used for displaying the booking calendar, and to be honest I don't know how to find this code. It is included in the page, but when the booking form is loaded via Ajax, the script for the calendar is not working.